# How to search SQL table with criteria like "queryPos<colA && queryPos>colB" most efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Updat
Thanks all for the suggestions. The DBMS is MSSQL, the table columns are as follow: it has composite key with 6 columns

[image]

My table in MSSQL db contains tens of millions of rows like

| Chromosome | StartPos | EndPos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 200 |
| A | 101 | 204 |
| B | 78 | 199 |
| B | 101 | 199 |
| C | 3 | 35 |

Now I have a list of objects with chromosome and pos

```
{{A, 105}, {B, 100}, ......},
```

I used .net entityFramework to connect my db and the search strategy is pretty straight-forward: loop through all entries in the list and

```
select * from table
where Chromosome == chr && StartPos > pos and EndPos < pos
```

It's running slow. I believe this is very inefficient, but I am not familiar with SQL. How to improve the query performance?

Thanks!

Comment: you should mention the db

Comment: If i undestamd correctly then you have > and < pointing the wrong direction. The where clause will match nothing if start dates are less than corresponding end date.

Comment: Btw, i dont know EF works, could you check if it is executing one query per `(char, pos)` pair?

Comment: We would need the table definition (including indexes) and the query plan to provide meaningful help here.

Comment: Also what DBMS this is for.

Comment: I added updates about the DBMS and table design. Hope that help. Suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Does your query even produce a result? If Start and End pos are 100 and 200 respectively then ***NO value for `x`*** satisfies the condition `100 > x and 200 < x`.